# Proper way to write a joint distribution combined of a conditional distribution a

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, conditional-probability

Let $\textbf{A}$ and $\textbf{B}$ denote a given sets. Suppose I have a conditional distribution $W_{Y|X}: \textbf{A} \rightarrow \textbf{B}$ where for each $a\in \textbf{A}$, $W_{Y|X}(\cdot | a)$ is a random variable on $\textbf{B}$.

Let $P$ and $Q$ be two other distribution of random variables on $A$ from which I want to generate 2 joint distribution: $P_{X,Y}=W_{Y|X}\cdot P$ and $Q_{X,Y}=W_{Y|X}\cdot Q$.

It this notation for the composition is acceptable? Is there other nicer way to or standard way to write this?

Comment: Apart from the proper way of writing this the question is what are the ingredients you are starting with: you have two random variables $X$ and $Y\,.$ Then what exactly are $W_{Y|X},P_X$ *and* $Q_X\,?$ Hint: $W_{Y|X}$ could be [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability_distribution#Conditional_continuous_distributions) but who knows.

Comment: I have edited the quastion but its still not clear as you mention. When writing $W_{Y|X}$ we do not need to have any random variable $X$, but writing it this way is standard in information theory.

Comment: $W_{Y|X}(\,.\,|a)$ is a random variable on $\mathbf B$ taking values in $\mathbf B\,?$ Possible but very confusing. Nothing stops you from multiplying that random variable with another random variable $P$ and call that $P_{X|Y}\,.$ You can use any notation you like. What I don't get is why those "random variables" are conditional, resp. joint distributions. You should give references.